# Expander closed when ListView is refreshed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expander

I have a `ListView` which has grouping enabled and a custom Style on ListView.GroupStyle: the `GroupStyle` is an `Expander`.

```
 <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
               <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                      <Expander Style="{DynamicResource SettingsExpander}">
                           <Expander.Header>
                                 <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource BigWhiteText}"
                                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                           </Expander.Header>
                        <Expander.Content>
                       <ItemsPresenter />
                      </Expander.Content>
                    </Expander>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
           </Style>
         </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      </GroupStyle>
   </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

One of these contains a `checkbox`: if it is checked, its following elements are enabled otherwise they are not.

[Image of the group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9AuT.png)

The problem that I'm having is that when the Checked value changes and the view is refreshed, the expander collapses. What can I do in order to keep it open?

Thanks!

**Edit**

My Expander style is the following:

```
<Style x:Key="SettingsExpander" TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource StandardBorderColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource StandardBackgroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It sounds like there is something in your SettingsExpander style that is changing Expander.IsExpanded.  It's probably a binding or a trigger in that style.  Share the style code if you can't figure out where this is happening.

Comment: I added the style. I don't think that the problem depends on it.